# Kendo grid change multiple selected cells value

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Let's say I have few rows of data populated with numbers. I want to select multiple cells and then on click on a button outside the grid change their values to some other number, let's say '8'. See the [sample](http://www.telerik.com/clientsfiles/d5893fb3-8e74-454c-bf1a-6bf767c4fa56_untitled.png?sfvrsn=0).

The guys at Telerik gave me this solution:

```
$(".change").click(function () {
    var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var cellsToChange = grid.select();

    for (var i = 0; i < cellsToChange.length; i++) {
        var item = grid.dataItem($(cellsToChange[i]).closest("tr"));
        item.ProductName = "new value";
    }

    grid.refresh();
});
```

But the problem is that I don't know which cells will be selected, so I can't work with `item.ProductName`, for example. Is there a way to set the value of all selected cells directly, something like `cellsToChange[i].value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either get the column name from `grid.columns` or from the corresponding `th` element. use the `grid.cellIndex` method to select the correct column:

```
$("#change").click(function() {
    var selected = grid.select();
    var header = grid.thead;
    for (var i = 0, max = selected.length ; i < max ; i++) {
        var index = grid.cellIndex(selected[i]);
        var th = $(header).find("th").eq(index);
        // could also use grid.columns[index].field 
        // (not sure if this gets reordered on column reorder though)
        var field = $(th).data("field");

        var item = grid.dataItem($(selected[i]).closest("tr"));
        item[field] = "new value";
    }

    grid.refresh();
});
```

Regarding your comment: 
`dataItem.set()` causes the `<tr>` elements to get removed from their context (because `grid.refresh()` will create new rows for the view), and because of that, `grid.dataItem()` won't give you the expected result with the old DOM elements you still have a reference to.

If you want to use `dataItem.set()`, you can try something like this as a work-around:

```
$("#change").click(function () {
    var selected = grid.select(),
        header = grid.thead,
        dataItem,
        index,
        field,
        value,
        th;

    for (var i = 0, max = selected.length; i < max; i++) {
        dataItem = grid.dataItem($(selected[i]).closest("tr"));
        index = $(selected[i]).index();
        th = $(header).find("th").eq(index);
        field = $(th).data("field");
        value = "new value " + i;

        setTimeout(function (dataItem, field, value) {
            return function () {
                dataItem.set(field, value);
            }
        }(dataItem, field, value), 5);
    }
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MKLG9/5/))

Comment: This is the way to do it! Thank you!

Comment: I just want to add that item.dirty = true should be added after the assignment of new value. That way the grid update/save can work properly. If someone wants the red marker indicating that the cell is dirty, .k-dirty-cell class should be added to the corresponding td element.

Comment: you can also use item.set(field, "new value") instead which will set the dirty property and also trigger the grid's change event (in that case you won't need the call to .refresh either)

Comment: if I use item.set(field, "new value") i get: "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'set' of undefined or null reference." var item gets assigned normally, then the change event on the dataSource is triggered, and then item is suddenly null. I can't figure out why this is happening?

Comment: thanks for the update. In IE10 now there is no JavaScript runtime error, but only few cells get edited, and then it all stops without any error logs. IE9, Firefox and Chrome work well. I noticed that your demo jsfiddle also works well in IE9, FF and Chrome, but it doesn't fill empty cells in IE10. I don't understand why IE10 has different behavior than other browsers. Do You maybe have any ideas?

Comment: the code still relied on getting the index from removed elements (those returned by grid.select()), which probably caused the bug; I changed it a bit - should work in IE 10 as well now (whenever you work with the DOM, you have to be prepared for a browser behaving different than others)

Comment: thanks, that works. If I select a lot of cells, the whole operation of changing values takes a while. Do you have any idea how I could put some sort of wait cursor or loading image? I've tried various stuff I found on stackoverflow, even kendo.ui.progress but nothing works.

Comment: if this is a problem, I'd actually go with the first approach (item[field] = "new value";) because it won't cause a refresh for each cell (which is causing the performance problem you're seeing); you can still trigger the change event manually if you need it (you may need to compose the change event manually, not sure what you need)

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you this way, but I'm getting desperate about the problem. Maybe because of your expertise you'd have some insights about my other problem with [cell refocusing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709698/kendo-grid-cell-refocusing-after-refresh). Anyways, if you'd be willing to give it a try, I'd be very thankful!

Comment: a demo typically increases your chances of getting help (and in general, upvoting helpful answers also is a nice incentive); in any case, I added a suggestion;

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve the ColumnList of your grid first and then loop through it

```
$(".change").click(function () {
    var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var columnsListOfView = grid.columns;
    var cellsToChange = grid.select();

    for (var j = 0; i < cellsToChange.length; i++) {
        var item = grid.dataItem($(cellsToChange[i]).closest("tr"));
        for (var j = 0; j < columnsListOfView.length; j++) {
         //Here columnsListOfView[j].field will give you the different names that you need 
         var field=columnsListOfView[j].field;
         item[field] = "new value";    
        }
    }

    grid.refresh();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but your solution iterates through all columns in the row. Lars Höppner's solution is what I needed. Your solution is good if we want to populate the whole row without using hard-coded column names, though.