# Kendo grid cell refocusing after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a selectable, navigatable and editable grid. After I enter a value in a cell, I have to change the value in the cell under the updated cell. To show the updated values of both cells, I have to refresh the grid. When I do that, the edited cell loses focus. I found a way to refocus the last edited cell during the save event:

```
save: function (e) {
    var focusedCellIndex = this.current()[0].cellIndex;    //gets the cell index of the currently focused cell

    //...some dataItem saving (dataItem.set()) logic...

    this.refresh();    //refreshing the grid instance

    setTimeout(function () {    //refocusing the cell
        return function () {
            var focusedCell = $("#grid tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "'] td:nth-child(" + (focusedCellIndex + 1) + ")");
            $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').editCell(focusedCell);
        }
    }(), 200);
}
```

The problem is that this works for the first time, but if I try to re-edit the same cell again, the cell loses focus. When I try to debug, it seems that `this.current()[0].cellIndex` returns **0** in the second attempt, and because of that cell focusing isn't working anymore.

Does anyone have any idea why `this.current()` works for the 1st time, and not for the 2nd time? Are there any other approaches for refocusing the cell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's difficult to say exactly what is happening without seeing it in a demo, so if you can, I'd suggest creating one for illustration. I'm guessing that the call to `refresh` is removing the current cell selection and focusing the first cell because the grid is navigatable (I don't quite understand the rationale behind that behavior, but it's hard to say whether it's a bug since we don't get to read Telerik's code comments).

One approach that might work would be to modify the `current` method to also store the current cell index:

```
kendo.ui.Grid.fn.refresh = (function(refresh) {
    return function(e) {
        this._refreshing = true;

        refresh.call(this, e);

        this._refreshing = false;
    }
})(kendo.ui.Grid.fn.refresh);

kendo.ui.Grid.fn.current = (function(current) {
    return function(element) {
        // assuming element is td element, i.e. cell selection
        if (!this._refreshing && element) {
            this._lastFocusedCellIndex = $(element).index(); // note this might break with grouping cells etc, see grid.cellIndex() method
            this._lastFocusedUid = $(element).closest("tr").data("uid");
        }

        return current.call(this, element);
    }
})(kendo.ui.Grid.fn.current);

kendo.ui.Grid.fn.refocusLastEditedCell = function () {
    if (this._lastFocusedUid ) {
        var row = $(this.tbody).find("tr[data-uid='" + this._lastFocusedUid + "']");
        var cell = $(row).children().eq(this._lastFocusedCellIndex);
        this.editCell(cell);
    }
};
```

That way, you should always be able to use `grid.refocusLastEditedCell()` when you need to.

Another idea:

```
save: function (e) {
    var focusedCell = this.current();
    var focusedCellIndex = focusedCell.index();    //gets the cell index of the currently focused cell

    //...some dataItem saving (dataItem.set()) logic...

    this.refresh();    //refreshing the grid instance

    // reset current cell..
    this.current(focusedCell);

    setTimeout(function () {    //refocusing the cell
        return function () {
            var focusedCell = $("#grid tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "'] td:nth-child(" + (focusedCellIndex + 1) + ")");
            $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').editCell(focusedCell);
        }
    }(), 200);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I think we're on to something with the 1st approach. `_lastFocusedCellIndex` is now working all the time. But, for example, if I edit cell 10 in row 3, it will be refocused; if I edit it again, focus will go to cell 10 in row 1. So, I just need to get the rowIndex (or uid) of the last focused cell's row. I tried expanding your version of `kendo.ui.Grid.fn.current` with `this._lastFocusedCell = $(element);` and then get cell's dataItem but the 2nd time it returns 1st dataItem of the grid.

Comment: you shouldn't use references to DOM elements since they get replaced when the grid refreshes; I updated my answer

Comment: thanks so much, it's working, even in IE :) and I'd give a +1 to every comment or answer you've made, but I don't have enough reputation yet :)

Comment: I suppose I can forget about validation because of grid refreshing? I'm trying with classic and custom validation in the dataSource model, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I haven't worked with validator in the grid, so I don't know; I'd expect it to prevent the save event in the first place if an edit isn't valid, so in that case, there shouldn't even be a refresh. This might be too complex to figure out in the comments.

Comment: OK, just one more question: I'm trying to iterate through cells horizontally after I enter a value, so I replaced `focusedCellIndex + 1` with `focusedCellIndex + 2`. It seems that `_lastFocusedCellIndex` gets updated only for the 1st time, because I can only switch to next cell when I start, then it keeps focusing the same cell. Is there a way to continuously update `_lastFocusedCellIndex`?

Comment: not sure I understand what you're doing; if you call editCell(cell) and want the cell to be remembered, you can explicitly call current(cell) as well

Comment: I've got a question for Lars; I'm trying to do a similar thing in my grid, but refreshing always loses the position. In his answer, he has the comment "// note this might break with grouping cells etc, see grid.cellIndex() method" - I don't have grouped cells but I do have locked cells and I always lose the position when I refresh. Any tips?

Comment: @loxdog don't have time to look into it now - I'd start by logging the cell index and $(element).html() to see whether it corresponds to what you clicked on (both from the current and refocusLastEditedCell method); also: are you talking about the cell not being in edit mode after refresh or the scroll position? if you create a demo I can take a look

Comment: Thank you @LarsHöppner and tstancin...I've spent hours the past few days trying to figure out why my Kendo Grid would automatically set focus to the very first cell after selecting from a custom Kendo DropDownList editor. Getting the edited cell/row indices and calling current worked for me. I <3 Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on the answer, but I'd like to thank you Lars Hoppner for your answer.  It helped me tremendously with the annoying refresh navigation problems of Kendo Grids.

I also would like to add that for grids with horizontal scroll bars, your solution will still cause the scroll to shift as far left as possible while keeping the last edited cell in view.  To prevent this bad behavior, I did the following:

```
grid.closeCell();
grid.refresh();
grid.refocusLastEditedCell();
```

Closing the cell before refreshing kept the scroll bars in place, now everything works great.  Hopefully this helps anyone else viewing your answer.

Comment: you could also save and restore the [$.scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) and $.scrollLeft values of the DOM element that has the scroll bars (.k-scrollbar-horizontal/vertical for regular scrolling or .k-virtual-scrollable-wrap when using virtual scrolling)

Comment: I haven't tried that and it sounds like it would work.  My only concern with that is the user may see the grid "flicker" as it quickly scrolls back and forth.  Haven't confirmed this though.