# Kendo Grid: Retaining navigational cell after a datasource sync

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

this is similar to a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515544/kendo-grid-how-to-update-data-source-from-code-when-the-row-changes) where I wanted to sync my data source when the user changes rows in the grid (exactly as Access saves out a record)

In the post above am am shown how to do this when the user tabs into a new cell as follows...

```
function refreshFix1() {
kendo.ui.Grid.fn.refresh = (function (refresh) {
  return function (e) {
    this._refreshing = true;

    refresh.call(this, e);

    this._refreshing = false;
  }
})(kendo.ui.Grid.fn.refresh);

kendo.ui.Grid.fn.current = (function (current) {
  return function (element) {
    // assuming element is td element, i.e. cell selection
    if (!this._refreshing && element) {
      this._lastFocusedCellIndex = $(element).index(); 
      this._lastFocusedUid = $(element).closest("tr").data("uid");

      // Added this For navigation mode
      this._lastNavigationCell = this.tbody.find("tr:last td:last");
    }

    return current.call(this, element);
  }
})(kendo.ui.Grid.fn.current);

kendo.ui.Grid.fn.refocusLastEditedCell = function () {
  if (this._lastFocusedUid) {
    var row = $(this.tbody).find("tr[data-uid='" + this._lastFocusedUid + "']");
    var cell = $(row).children().eq(this._lastFocusedCellIndex);
    this.editCell(cell);       
  }
};
```

The above gives us a function we can call (refocusLastEditedCell) after we sync the data source, and seems to work great.

I now want to do the same for when the grid is in **Navigation** mode. Following the above example, and the doco [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-current) , I added the following...

```
// Call this to go back to a cell in *navigation* mode
kendo.ui.Grid.fn.refocusLastNavigatedCell = function () {
    var self = this;
    if (this._lastNavigationCell) {   
        // try see if calling "async" using setTimeout will help
        setTimeout (function(){
        console.log("going back to navigation cell");
        self.current(this._lastNavigationCell);
        self.table.focus();
    }, 10)
    }
  };
```

I then have the following code to call sync on the datasource...

```
vm.gridData.sync(); 

if (vm.editMode){
   / Go back to edit cell
  grid.refocusLastEditedCell() 
} else{
   // Go back to navigation  cell
    grid.refocusLastNavigatedCell();
  };    
}
```

(full example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/peterjc/r28vmg6f/16/))

Unfortunately I do not seem to be going back to the same cell, it again just jumps to the top left cell.

Any ideas how to get it to work in this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the row uid and cell index as done in the [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709698/kendo-grid-cell-refocusing-after-refresh/22969403#22969403); the `<td>` element you're trying to focus doesn't exist anymore once the grid gets rerendered. So you could do this:

```
kendo.ui.Grid.fn.current = (function (current) {
    return function (element) {
        // assuming element is td element, i.e. cell selection
        if (!this._refreshing && element) {
            this._lastFocusedCellIndex = $(element).index();
            this._lastFocusedUid = $(element).closest("tr").data("uid");

            // For navigation mode
            var cell = current.call(this, element);
            this._lastNavigationCellIndex = $(cell).index();
            this._lastNavigationCellUid = $(cell).closest("tr").data("uid");
        }

        return current.call(this, element);
    }
})(kendo.ui.Grid.fn.current);
```

and use it:

```
kendo.ui.Grid.fn.refocusLastNavigatedCell = function () {
    if (this._lastNavigationCellUid) {
        var row = $(this.tbody).find("tr[data-uid='" + 
                    this._lastNavigationCellUid + "']");
        var cell = $(row).children().eq(this._lastNavigationCellIndex);
        this.current(cell);
    }
};
```

You've got so many customizations now, you may want to extend the grid itself instead of replacing its methods one by one.

By the way, you could probably integrate all of this in the refresh method, so you don't have to explicitly call it:

```
kendo.ui.Grid.fn.refresh = (function (refresh) {
    return function (e) {
        this._refreshing = true;

        refresh.call(this, e);

        this._refreshing = false;

        if (!this.options.editable) {
            this.refocusLastNavigatedCell();
        } else {
            this.refocusLastEditedCell()
        }
    }
})(kendo.ui.Grid.fn.refresh);
```

I didn't understand why you want to refocus

```
this.tbody.find("tr:last td:last");
```

so I changed it for the ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r28vmg6f/19/)).

Comment: Hi Lars, thank yo very much once again. The above appears to work perfectly. I see we need to search for the elements rather than saving a reference to objects that no longer exist. I will look into the extending the grid (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/widgets/create-custom-kendo-widget). What I was going to do is just have all these "extensions" put into a directive, so they are "out of the way" and don't clutter the controller, but perhaps doing the extension is a cleaner way to go. Anyway, thanks once again.